# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'error')

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, vuejs2, typeerror

I am working in VueJS and encountered this error.
How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find in your code a reference to `xyz.error`. The value of xyz is set to the value `null` instead of an object with property error.

Try a text search for the value `.error`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the xyz.error in your file with "typeof xyz != undefined && typeof xyz.error != undefined"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).